# Lexus IS F Curb Damage On Tire. Do I Need To Replace? HELP

Tags: tires, damage, lexus, sidewall-damage

[image][image]

I just recently curbed my rims on my Lexus IS F 250 every drivers pet peeve! The rim damage is fixable I know but my main concern is do I need to replace the tire? I see no threads , and there is no air leakage. It's honestly not deep I wouldn't even say an inch. It's mainly the tire protector part. My only stall is if I change one tire I have to change all. I don't drive on the freeway , I'm really not a everyday driver besides weekends.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the low-profile tire fitted on my IS350. I've had a few chunks missing from one of my tires for more than a year now without any issue.

You should be fine as long as that tear is pure rubber and the tire's wireframe hasn't been exposed.

Comment: Thanks I figured! Cause it's just the rubber just reading all the blogs makes me even more nervous about its not puncture deep so I figured it should be ok!

Comment: Keep an eye on it. If you see it start to bulge at all, don't drive it until you can get it replaced.